# To make background-image SVG work like an inline element

Tags: php, html, css, svg

I have such a text file

```
A
A+
ABAP
ABC
ABCL
ActionScript
ActiveBasic
Ada
Advanced Boolean Expression Language
Agena
AHDL
ALGOL
Alice
ash
APL
AppleScript
as
Atom
AutoIt
AutoLISP
AWK
B
Bash
BASIC
BCPL
Befunge
BF-BASIC'n
Bioera
BLISS
Bluespec
```

I wrote a code that reads this text file and uses its contents as the contents of the SVG text element. I wrote PHP code so that the color of the text element is randomly determined.

```
<?php
define("MAX", 1000);
$languages = "";
$data = file("text.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
for ($i = 0; $i < MAX; $i++) {
  $languages .= "<text x='0' y='15' fill='%23". sprintf("%06x",rand(0,0xffffff))  ."' font-size='20'>". $data[rand(0, count($data) - 1)] . " </text>";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8, <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' height='50px' width='120px'><?= $languages ?></svg>");
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#DDD;">
  <div class="box"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I was hoping that the text elements in the above code would be arranged like the span elements in the code below.

```html
<span style='color:#31ba5c'>ActiveBasic </span><span style='color:#5dcec7'>Advanced Boolean Expression Language </span><span style='color:#bf7a92'>AutoLISP </span><span style='color:#12fb43'>as </span><span style='color:#430ab5'>Agena </span><span style='color:#2eccdf'>BLISS </span>
<span style='color:#bbd0bf'>BASIC </span><span style='color:#79b352'>Atom </span><span style='color:#c11cf5'>A </span><span style='color:#d49603'>ABAP </span><span style='color:#998720'>ABAP </span><span style='color:#cf1bae'>ActiveBasic </span>
<span style='color:#d89613'>Alice </span>
<span style='color:#cdb6b5'>BASIC </span><span style='color:#dcf2c2'>Befunge </span><span style='color:#49bbba'>AutoIt </span><span style='color:#b6231f'>Alice </span><span style='color:#a2f049'>AppleScript </span><span style='color:#aeabad'>AppleScript </span>
<span style='color:#1b2b3a'>as </span>
<span style='color:#078643'>BF-BASIC'n </span><span style='color:#20d31c'>A+ </span><span style='color:#9cf845'>ActionScript </span><span style='color:#ad8616'>Bash </span><span style='color:#a804a7'>ActionScript </span><span style='color:#e82078'>Befunge </span>
<span style='color:#be5729'>APL </span>
<span style='color:#13e5d0'>BASIC </span><span style='color:#b756a2'>Atom </span><span style='color:#a1e50d'>ABC </span><span style='color:#71e8cc'>ActiveBasic </span><span style='color:#7430c9'>ash </span><span style='color:#ec9cdb'>AutoLISP </span>
<span style='color:#c03e0a'>Alice </span>
<span style='color:#325e95'>AWK </span><span style='color:#7887dc'>AppleScript </span><span style='color:#91cfaa'>BLISS </span><span style='color:#8821a2'>as </span><span style='color:#6de2af'>B </span><span style='color:#2ed5c7'>Agena </span>
<span style='color:#523219'>Ada </span>
<span style='color:#7a6705'>Advanced Boolean Expression Language </span><span style='color:#f6d8df'>AppleScript </span><span style='color:#7dd080'>Bluespec </span><span style='color:#3f4ebd'>Bluespec </span><span style='color:#64f53c'>AutoIt </span>
<span style='color:#a84b17'>A </span>
<span style='color:#c7df22'>ActionScript </span><span style='color:#e59eee'>AutoLISP </span><span style='color:#0e496c'>BASIC </span><span style='color:#350677'>Agena </span><span style='color:#989690'>Bluespec </span><span style='color:#3bfae8'>as </span>
<span style='color:#6e0965'>ALGOL </span>
<span style='color:#808236'>Bluespec </span><span style='color:#c01b5c'>Ada </span><span style='color:#7e4d59'>A+ </span><span style='color:#04cd4f'>AHDL </span><span style='color:#e0feb9'>BLISS </span><span style='color:#dde242'>AHDL </span>
<span style='color:#1ca195'>Befunge </span>
<span style='color:#e056ee'>ash </span><span style='color:#a7bb1e'>A+ </span><span style='color:#cfcf10'>AHDL </span><span style='color:#f68c08'>ABAP </span><span style='color:#f23b1d'>Alice </span><span style='color:#fac576'>Atom </span>
<span style='color:#96ea02'>as </span>
<span style='color:#2cc773'>BCPL </span><span style='color:#aeafe7'>ActionScript </span><span style='color:#cf28e4'>ABCL </span><span style='color:#0a096b'>AppleScript </span><span style='color:#886398'>AutoIt </span><span style='color:#95c909'>Agena </span>
<span style='color:#fe27e1'>AutoLISP </span><span style='color:#63d70f'>B </span><span style='color:#4948b5'>Bioera </span><span style='color:#c20a21'>Bluespec </span><span style='color:#641223'>AppleScript </span><span style='color:#0e542a'>Ada </span>
<span style='color:#07015b'>AutoLISP </span><span style='color:#43bbfa'>Ada </span><span style='color:#84d930'>AppleScript </span><span style='color:#3e3086'>Ada </span><span style='color:#9a971a'>A+ </span><span style='color:#8f68a8'>Bluespec </span>
<span style='color:#f546c0'>ALGOL </span><span style='color:#0042c5'>AWK </span><span style='color:#b51a31'>Bioera </span><span style='color:#a2095e'>Agena </span><span style='color:#1d4694'>as </span><span style='color:#84ef89'>AWK </span>
<span style='color:#716a49'>Bluespec </span>
<span style='color:#533273'>BLISS </span><span style='color:#e66f5a'>A </span><span style='color:#538f61'>APL </span><span style='color:#21e7f0'>ABCL </span><span style='color:#479c01'>Ada </span><span style='color:#1f718d'>Atom </span>
<span style='color:#18fece'>Alice </span>
<span style='color:#a1cd28'>AutoIt </span><span style='color:#8255e8'>APL </span><span style='color:#91d1d2'>as </span><span style='color:#eda45a'>APL </span><span style='color:#51f2e5'>AutoIt </span><span style='color:#0ccd6b'>ActiveBasic </span>
<span style='color:#4520a5'>Befunge </span><span style='color:#4365e8'>A </span><span style='color:#800db7'>Alice </span><span style='color:#c80c70'>AppleScript </span><span style='color:#78749c'>Ada </span><span style='color:#3f086c'>Bluespec </span>
<span style='color:#d0a86f'>BF-BASIC'n </span><span style='color:#b8ca39'>Befunge </span><span style='color:#df5aca'>A </span><span style='color:#011491'>ABAP </span><span style='color:#a4a074'>Bash </span><span style='color:#b94027'>ActiveBasic </span>
<span style='color:#73073f'>AHDL </span><span style='color:#ec1460'>as </span><span style='color:#236656'>Alice </span><span style='color:#dfbe63'>A </span><span style='color:#38721e'>BLISS </span><span style='color:#def098'>Alice </span>
<span style='color:#154950'>Bluespec </span><span style='color:#ef4dcc'>APL </span><span style='color:#67af76'>AutoLISP </span><span style='color:#f40002'>Alice </span><span style='color:#243572'>B </span><span style='color:#ebb3b3'>Befunge </span>
<span style='color:#b0c34c'>ALGOL </span><span style='color:#6889a0'>Atom </span><span style='color:#c0c787'>ABCL </span><span style='color:#1a2cd0'>AutoIt </span><span style='color:#f6be13'>ABC </span><span style='color:#3ef23a'>A+ </span>
<span style='color:#2d8350'>AutoIt </span><span style='color:#6f20cc'>ABAP </span><span style='color:#d31929'>ALGOL </span><span style='color:#72ec3b'>Advanced Boolean Expression Language </span><span style='color:#81af15'>A </span>
<span style='color:#e1fcd4'>A+ </span><span style='color:#f67ef6'>Ada </span><span style='color:#7324c4'>ash </span><span style='color:#9de88f'>Atom </span><span style='color:#7f910b'>Befunge </span><span style='color:#401796'>AppleScript </span>
<span style='color:#00c0df'>Bluespec </span><span style='color:#048021'>Ada </span><span style='color:#fe869d'>BASIC </span><span style='color:#c02088'>Advanced Boolean Expression Language </span><span style='color:#cb82cc'>ABAP </span>
<span style='color:#9ee321'>BCPL </span><span style='color:#91a336'>ABAP </span><span style='color:#d94558'>AHDL </span><span style='color:#6c6797'>BLISS </span><span style='color:#7a9021'>ABAP </span><span style='color:#78f184'>BCPL </span>
<span style='color:#c3c60b'>Atom </span><span style='color:#414259'>Ada </span><span style='color:#96154b'>ALGOL </span>
```

However, the text element became bulky and the design broke due to the number of characters.

How can I make SVG behave like an inline element like the above span element and change it according to screen size?

Comment: Quick note that you can generate a random hex colour with `sprintf("%06x",rand(0,0xffffff))`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thank you for giving me good knowledge! My color code generation process became even smarter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG does not have automatic layout like HTML.  It is a graphic language which requires that you specify the positions and sizes of all the objects in it.

You have one option as long as your SVGs are only ever going to be displayed in a browser.  You can use a `<foreignObject>` to embed some HTML in your SVG.

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <rect x="5" y="5" width="490" height="490" rx="20" fill="linen"/>

  <foreignObject x="40" y="40" width="420" height="420">
    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <span style='color:#31ba5c'>ActiveBasic </span><span style='color:#5dcec7'>Advanced Boolean Expression Language </span><span style='color:#bf7a92'>AutoLISP </span><span style='color:#12fb43'>as </span><span style='color:#430ab5'>Agena </span><span style='color:#2eccdf'>BLISS </span>
      <span style='color:#bbd0bf'>BASIC </span><span style='color:#79b352'>Atom </span><span style='color:#c11cf5'>A </span><span style='color:#d49603'>ABAP </span><span style='color:#998720'>ABAP </span><span style='color:#cf1bae'>ActiveBasic </span>
      <span style='color:#d89613'>Alice </span>
<span style='color:#cdb6b5'>BASIC </span><span style='color:#dcf2c2'>Befunge </span><span style='color:#49bbba'>AutoIt </span><span style='color:#b6231f'>Alice </span><span style='color:#a2f049'>AppleScript </span><span style='color:#aeabad'>AppleScript </span>
      <span style='color:#1b2b3a'>as </span>
<span style='color:#078643'>BF-BASIC'n </span><span style='color:#20d31c'>A+ </span><span style='color:#9cf845'>ActionScript </span><span style='color:#ad8616'>Bash </span><span style='color:#a804a7'>ActionScript </span><span style='color:#e82078'>Befunge </span>
      <span style='color:#be5729'>APL </span>
      <span style='color:#13e5d0'>BASIC </span><span style='color:#b756a2'>Atom </span><span style='color:#a1e50d'>ABC </span><span style='color:#71e8cc'>ActiveBasic </span><span style='color:#7430c9'>ash </span><span style='color:#ec9cdb'>AutoLISP </span>
      <span style='color:#c03e0a'>Alice </span>
<span style='color:#325e95'>AWK </span><span style='color:#7887dc'>AppleScript </span><span style='color:#91cfaa'>BLISS </span><span style='color:#8821a2'>as </span><span style='color:#6de2af'>B </span><span style='color:#2ed5c7'>Agena </span>
      <span style='color:#523219'>Ada </span>
      <span style='color:#7a6705'>Advanced Boolean Expression Language </span><span style='color:#f6d8df'>AppleScript </span><span style='color:#7dd080'>Bluespec </span><span style='color:#3f4ebd'>Bluespec </span><span style='color:#64f53c'>AutoIt </span>
      <span style='color:#a84b17'>A </span>
      <span style='color:#c7df22'>ActionScript </span><span style='color:#e59eee'>AutoLISP </span><span style='color:#0e496c'>BASIC </span><span style='color:#350677'>Agena </span><span style='color:#989690'>Bluespec </span><span style='color:#3bfae8'>as </span>
      <span style='color:#6e0965'>ALGOL </span>
      <span style='color:#808236'>Bluespec </span><span style='color:#c01b5c'>Ada </span><span style='color:#7e4d59'>A+ </span><span style='color:#04cd4f'>AHDL </span><span style='color:#e0feb9'>BLISS </span><span style='color:#dde242'>AHDL </span>
      <span style='color:#1ca195'>Befunge </span>
      <span style='color:#e056ee'>ash </span><span style='color:#a7bb1e'>A+ </span><span style='color:#cfcf10'>AHDL </span><span style='color:#f68c08'>ABAP </span><span style='color:#f23b1d'>Alice </span><span style='color:#fac576'>Atom </span>
      <span style='color:#96ea02'>as </span>
      <span style='color:#2cc773'>BCPL </span><span style='color:#aeafe7'>ActionScript </span><span style='color:#cf28e4'>ABCL </span><span style='color:#0a096b'>AppleScript </span><span style='color:#886398'>AutoIt </span><span style='color:#95c909'>Agena </span>
      <span style='color:#fe27e1'>AutoLISP </span><span style='color:#63d70f'>B </span><span style='color:#4948b5'>Bioera </span><span style='color:#c20a21'>Bluespec </span><span style='color:#641223'>AppleScript </span><span style='color:#0e542a'>Ada </span>
      <span style='color:#07015b'>AutoLISP </span><span style='color:#43bbfa'>Ada </span><span style='color:#84d930'>AppleScript </span><span style='color:#3e3086'>Ada </span><span style='color:#9a971a'>A+ </span><span style='color:#8f68a8'>Bluespec </span>
      <span style='color:#f546c0'>ALGOL </span><span style='color:#0042c5'>AWK </span><span style='color:#b51a31'>Bioera </span><span style='color:#a2095e'>Agena </span><span style='color:#1d4694'>as </span><span style='color:#84ef89'>AWK </span>
      <span style='color:#716a49'>Bluespec </span>
      <span style='color:#533273'>BLISS </span><span style='color:#e66f5a'>A </span><span style='color:#538f61'>APL </span><span style='color:#21e7f0'>ABCL </span><span style='color:#479c01'>Ada </span><span style='color:#1f718d'>Atom </span>
      <span style='color:#18fece'>Alice </span>
      <span style='color:#a1cd28'>AutoIt </span><span style='color:#8255e8'>APL </span><span style='color:#91d1d2'>as </span><span style='color:#eda45a'>APL </span><span style='color:#51f2e5'>AutoIt </span><span style='color:#0ccd6b'>ActiveBasic </span>
      <span style='color:#4520a5'>Befunge </span><span style='color:#4365e8'>A </span><span style='color:#800db7'>Alice </span><span style='color:#c80c70'>AppleScript </span><span style='color:#78749c'>Ada </span><span style='color:#3f086c'>Bluespec </span>
      <span style='color:#d0a86f'>BF-BASIC'n </span><span style='color:#b8ca39'>Befunge </span><span style='color:#df5aca'>A </span><span style='color:#011491'>ABAP </span><span style='color:#a4a074'>Bash </span><span style='color:#b94027'>ActiveBasic </span>
      <span style='color:#73073f'>AHDL </span><span style='color:#ec1460'>as </span><span style='color:#236656'>Alice </span><span style='color:#dfbe63'>A </span><span style='color:#38721e'>BLISS </span><span style='color:#def098'>Alice </span>
      <span style='color:#154950'>Bluespec </span><span style='color:#ef4dcc'>APL </span><span style='color:#67af76'>AutoLISP </span><span style='color:#f40002'>Alice </span><span style='color:#243572'>B </span><span style='color:#ebb3b3'>Befunge </span>
      <span style='color:#b0c34c'>ALGOL </span><span style='color:#6889a0'>Atom </span><span style='color:#c0c787'>ABCL </span><span style='color:#1a2cd0'>AutoIt </span><span style='color:#f6be13'>ABC </span><span style='color:#3ef23a'>A+ </span>
      <span style='color:#2d8350'>AutoIt </span><span style='color:#6f20cc'>ABAP </span><span style='color:#d31929'>ALGOL </span><span style='color:#72ec3b'>Advanced Boolean Expression Language </span><span style='color:#81af15'>A </span>
      <span style='color:#e1fcd4'>A+ </span><span style='color:#f67ef6'>Ada </span><span style='color:#7324c4'>ash </span><span style='color:#9de88f'>Atom </span><span style='color:#7f910b'>Befunge </span><span style='color:#401796'>AppleScript </span>
<span style='color:#00c0df'>Bluespec </span><span style='color:#048021'>Ada </span><span style='color:#fe869d'>BASIC </span><span style='color:#c02088'>Advanced Boolean Expression Language </span><span style='color:#cb82cc'>ABAP </span>
      <span style='color:#9ee321'>BCPL </span><span style='color:#91a336'>ABAP </span><span style='color:#d94558'>AHDL </span><span style='color:#6c6797'>BLISS </span><span style='color:#7a9021'>ABAP </span><span style='color:#78f184'>BCPL </span>
      <span style='color:#c3c60b'>Atom </span><span style='color:#414259'>Ada </span><span style='color:#96154b'>ALGOL </span>
    </body>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Comment: I had overlooked how to embed HTML with a foreignObject element. I can realize the purpose by using this. One concern is that the HTML embedded in the foreignObject element is interpreted by the browser as HTML and spoken to the screen reader even though it is the background. It is not written at least in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject), but does the foreignObject element behave like this?

Comment: I think you'll need to try it.  It will depend on how you are including the SVG in the page.

Comment: I embed SVG using the [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) in the `background-image` property. As far as I checked accessibility trees with developer tools, I realized that the screen reader did not read the HTML embedded in SVG. Thank you.